Does this integral, related to the Fresnel integrals, have a name or a known solution?
I've been working on a problem in light propagation, where the crux of a derivation boils down to understanding the following integral:
$$\int_{-x_0}^{x_0} e^{i \alpha \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx, $$
with the square root taking the positive imaginary branch when $x_0 > 1$. Unfortunately, I just have not been able to figure out whether this integral has a name, is trivially related to any named integrals, or find a tabulated result! I've asked humans, Wolfram Alpha, and ChatGPT, with no success.
The related Fresnel integrals would allow one to solve an approximation to this integral when $x_0 << 1$
$$e^{i\alpha} \int_{-x_0}^{x_0} e^{- i \frac{\alpha}{2} x^2} dx. $$
But, I also haven't seen this integral appear in tables of integrals related to the Fresnel integrals.
Has anyone come across this integral before, or know of more information about it?

It has a form with the “incomplete Bessel functions”, but it is uncommon. You can get a series using the Jacobi Anger expansion and substituting $x=\sin(t)$

Case 1: $|x_0|\leq 1$
The integral in question can be written in the form of an infinite series that involves Bessel functions. There are multiple ways of arriving to these results. Here, I will compute the integrals
$$I_1(\alpha)=\int_0^{\arcsin x_0}\cos\theta\cos(\alpha\cos\theta),~~~ I_2(\alpha)=\int_0^{\arcsin x_0}\cos\theta\sin(\alpha\cos\theta)$$
which constitute the real and imaginary part of the integral in question. One can proceed by expanding the sine/cosine in a Taylor series, due to the fact that integrals over powers of cosines can be expressed in closed form, in terms of Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind
$$\int_{0}^{\arcsin x_0}(\cos\theta)^{2m+1}d\theta=\frac{x_0}{2^{2m}}\sum_{k=0}^m{2m+1\choose m-k}\frac{U_{2k}\left(\sqrt{1-x_0^2}\right)}{2k+1}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\arcsin x_0}(\cos\theta)^{2m+2}d\theta=\frac{\arcsin x_0}{2^{2m+2}}{2m+2\choose m+1}+\frac{x_0}{2^{2m+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{m}{2m+2\choose m-k}\frac{U_{2k+1}\left(\sqrt{1-x_0^2}\right)}{2k+2}$$
Substituting these into the Taylor series for $I_1, I_2$ and exchanging the order of summation we get the following results:
$$I_1(\alpha)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x_0U_{2k}\left(\sqrt{1-x_0^2}\right)}{2k+1}[J_{2k}(\alpha)+J_{2k+2}(\alpha)]$$
$$I_2(\alpha)=\frac{J_1(\alpha)\arcsin x_0 }{2}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x_0U_{2k+1}\left(\sqrt{1-x_0^2}\right)}{2k+2}[J_{2k+1}(\alpha)+J_{2k+3}(\alpha)]$$
where $J_n$ are the Bessel functions of order $n$. Case 2 to be done later.

The integral can be simplified a bit:
$$I=2\int_{0}^{x_0} e^{i \alpha \sqrt{1-x^2}} dx,$$
I would suggest trying the following change in the power of the exponent:
Instead of
$$\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$$
use
$$(1-x)^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
Then
$$I=2\int_{0}^{x_0} e^{i \alpha (1-x)^{\frac{1}{4}}} dx,$$
The last integral can be calculated already in closed form in elementary functions.

